# How to send message to room clients when a client disconnects

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want the server to send a message to all room clients when one of them disconnects.

Something like this:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    server.sockets.in(room).emit('bye');
});
```

But...

- How do I know which room to broadcast?
- What if the client has joined to multiple rooms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After inspecting the sockets object, I came up with this solution:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    var rooms = io.sockets.manager.roomClients[socket.id];
    for (var room in rooms) {
        if (room.length > 0) { // if not the global room ''
            room = room.substr(1); // remove leading '/'
            console.log('user exits: '+room);
            server.sockets.in(room).emit('bye');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: But it looks like from this solution you are going to emit 'bye' in every room the user is connected to, not just the one they left?

Comment: When the user disconnects, it leaves all channels. So it emits bye to all joined channels.

Comment: Let's say I am joined into 3 different rooms in three tabs in my browser and I close tab 3.  I shouldn't see a bye message in rooms 1 and 2.  Each tab has it's own socket id.

Comment: On my implementation each tab is like a different user (from node point of view).

Answer (score 0):

not 100% on this - but give it a try:

when connecting to a room  or adding a new user to the mix, remember their username or id or something in the socket:

```
socket.on('adduser', function(username){
    socket.username = username;
    socket.join('room');
}
```

Then listen to leave events on rooms:

```
socket.room.on('leave', function(){
    socket.broadcast.to(this).emit(socket.username + ' says seeya!');
}
```

It's worth a try anyway - I'm sure something similar will work if this doesn't.

Comment: Nope, `socket.room` is undefined.

Comment: You're right - that won't work after all - you need to just add a subscribe / unsubscribe functions - check out this chat example with rooms that show presence in a room - it will do basically what you need to do.  http://udidu.blogspot.ca/2012/11/chat-evolution-nodejs-and-socketio.html

Comment: Thanks but on the example you posted what i want is done in the function `disconnect()` of the `server.js` which has the same code with the accepted answer here and which is not the ideal way(for me) since you have to manually find the room that the user is leaving.